# JavascriptInterface not working with proguard on Android 4.2

Tags: android, android-webview, proguard

I have an issue since android 4.2 with proguard.

Basically I use a JavascriptInterface on a webview like this:

```
public class MyJavascriptInterface {
    public void doSomething() { ... }
}
```

Now what I do understand is that when proguard obfuscates the code it renames the class name and method name, so it cannot be called from Javascript anymore. That is why I have to add this to the proguard config:

```
-keepclassmembers class mypackage.MyJavascriptInterface { 
    public void doSomething();
}
```

When I set the target sdk to 17 (Android 4.2) I have to add the `@JavascriptInterface` annotation to my Javascript interface method for security reasons:

```
@JavascriptInterface
public class MyJavascriptInterface {
    public void doSomething() { ... }
}
```

Now the problem is that this does not work anymore if proguard is enabled (doSomething is not called as if the class is still renamed in the obfuscation step).
If I disable proguard the code works fine.

How can I make this work with target sdk 17?

Comment: For me the javascript interface function are not being called please tell me what should i do???

Comment: Can't say with this description of your problem... You could open a new question and describe your setup in detail, maybe post the relevant android and javascript code ;)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17637530/9636

and

http://stackoverflow.com/a/28034176/9636

are more generalized answers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to configure proguard for javascript interface?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17629507/how-to-configure-proguard-for-javascript-interface)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have found the solution, I just have to tell proguard to keep the `JavascriptInterface` annotation. I added this to my proguard configuration to make it work:

```
-keepattributes JavascriptInterface
```

Answer (score 3):

To preserve any annotations, you have to add the following to your ProGuard configuration:

```
-keepattributes *Annotation*
```

Class files represent the JavascriptInterface annotation as a class attribute of the type "RuntimeAnnotation" with a value "android.webkit.JavascriptInterface".

Comment: You only need `-keepattributes *Annotation*` if you're using obfuscation. http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/usage.html#obfuscationoptions

Answer (score 3):

Through looking at the mapping.txt and dump.txt files generated, and a lot of trial and error (I compiled 34 APK files to figure this out), I came up with this working solution:

```
-keep public class com.yourfullpackagename.Yourapp$JavaScriptInterface
-keepclassmembers class com.yourfullpackagename.Yourapp$JavaScriptInterface {*;}
-keepattributes com.yourfullpackagename.Yourapp$JavaScriptInterface
-keepattributes *Annotation*
```

(This assume JavaScriptInterface as an inner-class in an Activity called Yourapp in the com.yourfullpackagename namespace. Adjust accordingly for your app.)