# How to configure proguard for javascript interface?

Tags: android, obfuscation, proguard

I have a implemented a Webview which takes use of JavascriptInterface. It's working fine when not obfuscating, but at once Proguard is active, it does not work. I've looked here at other answers, but i still can't get it working.

**Some of the WebView class:**

```
public class Activity_Webview {
private WebView webView;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface (), "HTMLOUT");
        webView.setWebViewClient(mWebViewClient);
    }

    public class JavaScriptInterface implements NonObfuscateable{
        @JavascriptInterface
        public void processHTML(String html) {
        handleFinishFromWebView(html);
    }
}
```

**What i've tried in Proguard**:

```
-keep public class * implements com.project.NonObfuscateable
-keepclassmembers class * implements NonObfuscateable {
    public void processHTML(java.lang.String);
}
```

**I've also tried this (when not implementing NonObfuscateable interface**:

```
-keep public class com.project.Activity_Webview.JavaScriptInterface
-keep public class * implements com.project.Activity_Webview.JavaScriptInterface
-keepclassmembers class * implements com.project.Activity_Webview.JavaScriptInterface {
    <fields>;
    <methods>;
}
```

Does anybody have an idea of what could be wrong?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't know why I use default proguard-rule.pro file (it seems not set anything) in Android Studio 4.1.2 and everything goes right after the build with minifyEnabled=true.

Answer (score 50):

Both your configurations could have worked if they hadn't contained typos:

- ProGuard requires fully qualified names:

  `NonObfuscateable` -> `com.project.NonObfuscateable`
- Compiled classes use '$' as a separator for inner classes:

  `com.project.Activity_Webview.JavaScriptInterface` -> `com.project.Activity_Webview$JavaScriptInterface`

In the console log, ProGuard prints out notes about such suspected typos.

A more general solution for keeping annotated Javascript interface methods:

```
-keepclassmembers class * {
    @android.webkit.JavascriptInterface <methods>;
}
```

Comment: With newer ProGuard we should use `-keepclassmembers,allowoptimization`, right?

Answer (score 5):

If you're using obfuscation, in addition to [Eric Lafortune's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17637530/9636) you also need:

```
-keepattributes JavascriptInterface
```

http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/usage.html#obfuscationoptions

Comment: Indeed, according to a statement by @Eric Lafortune on a bug report, "ProGuard is currently agnostic about the meaning of any annotations". That's unfortunate… http://sourceforge.net/p/proguard/bugs/491/

Answer (score 4):

In my case work only code:

proguard.cfg:

```
-dontwarn

-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes SetJavaScriptEnabled
-keepattributes JavascriptInterface
-keepattributes InlinedApi
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-keepattributes *Annotation*

-keepclassmembers class * {
    @android.webkit.JavascriptInterface <methods>;
}
-keepclassmembers class * {
    @android.webkit.JavascriptInterface <methods>;
}
-keepclassmembers class **.*$MyJavascriptInterface {
    *;
}
-keepclassmembers class **.*$JavaScriptInterface {
    *;
}

-keep public class **.*$MyJavascriptInteface
-keep public class **.*$JavaScriptInterface
```

Java code:

```
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
public class ActivityWebView extends Activity {
    ...
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavascriptInterface(MyActivity.this), "MyJSI");

    ....

    public class MyJavaScriptInterface {

        Context context;

        MyJavascriptInterface(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        }

        @JavascriptInterface
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        public void myjavascriptfunction() {
            ...
        }

    }
    ...
}
```